# Does checking for function exists prevent browser garbage collection from freeing memory?

Tags: javascript, ajax, memory, garbage-collection, memory-leaks

I have JavaScript in file A which loads file B (through a jquery AJAX load) into element X.  On success, file A calls resizewin (below) which checks if the function resizeContent exists (which was in B), and if so executes it.  File A then removes DOM element X.

```
function resizewin() {
  if (typeof(resizeContent) === 'function') resizeContent();
}
```

In chrome I see detached DOM tree elements (well after I .remove() the X element).  I'm trying to track down the cause.  Could the above be the cause?  In other words, does checking if a function exists in the element and then calling that function prevent the browser garbage collection from deleting element X even after it is removed from the DOM?

If so, what is the right way to do this?

---

EDIT: Adding more code as requested.  Here is how I load B into the DOM (from file A):

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  contenttype: "application/html",
  dataType: 'html',
  url: url,
  data: dataarr,
  success: function(response) { $('#'+element).html(response); }
});
```

and in file B my function:

```
function resizeContent() {
  console.log("In resizeContent");
}
```

Comment: *“…does checking if a function exists in the element and then calling that function prevent the browser garbage collection from deleting element X even after it is removed from the DOM?”* No. Can you show more code?

Comment: I think it does.  When a loaded a new element via jaxa containing a function called resizeContent the old deteched element seemed to dissappear.  I think...but would love to hear an informed view